# "Due to buy a house" vs "due to look for a house"

Tags: meaning, differences, ambiguity

I know that "due to do something" is the correct way. For example:

> Sometime next month, we're **due to buy a house** in Rutherford.

However,

> Sometime next month, we're **due to look for a house** in Rutherford.

This sentence sounds weird to me because of the verb *look*. Can we use the verb *look* with *due to* in the sentence?

Comment: I don't see that there's any difference, grammatically.  "Due to look" sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two are grammatically the same. The reason it might sound weird (and it does to me, as well) is the association of the word 'due'. It implies a fixed moment.  'Look for' doesn't have the sense of completeness that 'buy' has.
I would say 'planning to look for' and 'due to buy' a house.
For the same reason, I would say 'planning to think about' and 'due to make a decision about' something.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the stop that's bugging you might be that you're seeing 'look for' and thinking the 'to' and 'for' are two preposition like words that are too close together.

I may be wrong. But in either case, I'm with @Nate and I think that considering 'to look for' as the verb, it is grammatically the same.